# Converting date serial numbers to actual dates

Tags: matlab

I have a variable `timestamp` of size 1x8734. They are date serial numbers and say first 3 elements are like this:

```
1.0e+05 *

    7.3618    7.3620    7.3620
```

If I use `datestr`, I can get the date and times in proper format.

My question is: I need to use those date and times in a loop form in my code. The first date being `Aug-04-2015 hh:mm:ss`. Suppose I need to choose all the dates in August, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: can you please share your matlab code by which you get this timestamp matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `timestamp` as numbers, and just compare to a predefined date, like this:

```
timestamp = randi(180,10,1)+1.0e+05 * 7.3609; % some arbitrary dates
starts = datenum('1-Aug-2015');
ends = datenum('31-Aug-2015');
for k = 1:numel(timestamp)
    if timestamp(k)>=starts && timestamp(k)<=ends
        % things to do...
        disp(datestr(timestamp(k)))
    end
end
```

And you can go further and vectorize this with:

```
Aug_dates = timestamp>=starts & timestamp<=ends;
disp(datestr(timestamp(Aug_dates)))
```

So, for a random set of dates like:

```
11-Jul-2015
09-Jul-2015
18-May-2015
29-Oct-2015
23-Aug-2015
12-Oct-2015
20-Aug-2015
14-Oct-2015
16-Sep-2015
05-Oct-2015
```

you will get in both cases the result:

```
23-Aug-2015
20-Aug-2015
```

Comment: Thanks so much. will try this

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using:

```
timestamp = 1.0e+05 * [ 7.3618  7.3620  7.3599  7.3620 ];
% I have included another value, i.e. 7.3599, for better understanding.
% 7.3599 is: 26-Jan-2015
abc = datestr(timestamp);

rowsabc = size(abc,1); 
def = cell(rowsabc,1); %Pre-allocation
for k = 1:rowsabc      %Using it in a loop as you said
    def{k}= strfind(abc(k,:),'Aug'); % finding which dates include 'Aug'
end

required = abc(~cellfun('isempty', def),:); %removing the rows of abc not containing 'Aug'
```

Or alternatively, you can avoid the loop using:

```
timestamp = 1.0e+05 * [ 7.3618  7.3620  7.3599  7.3620 ];
abc = datestr(timestamp);
temp = abc.'; temp=temp(:).';
required = abc(ceil(strfind(temp,'Aug')./11),:);
```

Both give the following result:

```
>> abc

abc =
04-Aug-2015
24-Aug-2015
26-Jan-2015
24-Aug-2015

>> required

required =
04-Aug-2015
24-Aug-2015
24-Aug-2015
```